# How to align bootstrap colums when setting margin of container to 0?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a question about aligning two bootstrap divs beside each other horizontally, whereas the left image "in one div" should have no margin to the left and the right text "in the other div" should be centered besides the image to the left. The right div may have some margin to the right
For some reason when I set my two divs beside each other and set margin to 0, I receive this result here as on the pic.

[image]
As can be seen, the div overlaps the other, why does that happen? What would I need to do in order to make it properly aligning to the right in the center? 
I tried using col-md-offset-1 but it only displays it below the picture. What can I do best to keep it properly aligned to the right?

This is my html / css:

```css
.row-provider-signup {
  margin-top:6em;
  margin-bottom:4em;
  text-align:center;
}

.container-provider-signup > [class*="container"] {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}

.provider-signup-header-text {
  color: #212121;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 62px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 72px;
  margin-bottom:1.5em;
}

.provider-signup-body-text {
  color: #616161;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:6em;
}

.provider-signup-button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4a90e2;
}

.provider-signup-button-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-provider-signup">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-provider-signup">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="{{route('cacheImage', ['newDesign', 'panorama-signup.png']) }}"/>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="provider-signup-header-text">Test Header</p>
            <p class="provider-signup-body-text">
              Test Text <br/><br/>
              Test Text <br/><br/>
              Test Text <br/>
            </p>
            <button class="btn provider-signup-button"><span class="provider-signup-button-text">SIGN UP</span></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `.container` is supposed to keep your content centered on various screen widths of various devices. If you don't need it, don't use it, rather than trying to change it. Use a custom class and add whatever code you need to it. Please note you have two types of containers in Bootstrap: `.container` and `.container-fluid`. In its current form, your question is unclear. Please specify in clear what is the desired result/effect. Most probably it's easier to achieve it without using `.container` the way you are trying to, rather than trying to override its CSS.

Comment: Well, I know of container-fluid, I use it for full sized width images, like my header and footer, I know that .container keeps content centered on various screens, thats why I try to keep it. When I try to remove container class, then my image gets too big and it stretches over the limit of the screen.

Comment: Don't keep it. It centers by having a fixed size on various intervals and left and right margins set to `auto` . You don't want to mess with it's width, or to rely on the difference between its set width and the screen width, because it's various. That's its purpose. To unify a content width so it's easier to adapt your content to various devices.

Comment: What I try to achieve is that the picture on the left and the text on the right is beside one another on the same row and centered

Comment: Centered how? Vertically? Horizontally? Both? Don't answer. Edit your question so that it is clear what you are asking for and what you have tried so far, eventually saying why you think it fails.